# The Context Menu for a Shell Extension is Not Appearing in the Folder View in Explorer

Tags: c++, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I have a Windows Shell Namespace extension mounted at a file location using the `desktop.ini` file with the CLSID for my namespace extension specified.

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
CLSID2={abcdef01-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcdef012345}
```

However, my context menu for the namespace extension only appears in the tree view in explorer and not in the folder view when selecting the root node of the namespace extension.

When I set a breakpoint in the namespace extension's `CreateViewObject` method, I can see that when I right click on the folder in the treeview, I get calls with an `riid` of `IID_IDropTarget` and `IID_IContextMenu`. However, when I right click on the folder in the folder view area, I only get a calls with the `riid` of `IID_IDropTarget`.

Is there something I need to specify in the registry or in the desktop.ini to properly get the folder view to behave the same way as the tree view?

Note: My definitions of Tree View and Folder View come from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144095(v=vs.85).aspx#explorer) on MSDN.

Comment: What the interface has method GetViewObject? IShellFolder has CreateViewObject and GetUIObjectOf but there is no GetViewObject. Do you use your own implementation of ShellView or use DefView?

Comment: We are using DefView. The `GetViewObject` was an internal method that is called by the `CreateViewObject` implementation.

Comment: Shell requests implementation of IContextMenu via IShellFolder.GetUIObjectOf. Does your implementation of GetUIObjectOf call your function CreateViewObject?

Comment: The GetUIObjectOf does make a call to create context menu (the same one that CreateViewObject does), however it does not get called in this case. Note: I updated the question to be more clear about when the menus do not appear. It is only a problem on the root node; once completely in my namespace extension, the menus appear as expected.